# SwiftUI Casting TupleView to an array of AnyView

Tags: swift, swiftui

## Code

I have the following code:

```swift
struct CustomTabView: View where Content: View {

    let children: [AnyView]

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content

        let m = Mirror(reflecting: content())
        if let value = m.descendant("value") {
            let tupleMirror = Mirror(reflecting: value)
            let tupleElements = tupleMirror.children.map({ AnyView($0.value) }) // ERROR
            self.children = tupleElements
        } else {
            self.children = [AnyView]()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(self.children) { child in
            child...
        }
    }
}
```

## Problem

I'm trying to convert the `TupleView` into an array of `AnyView` but I'm receiving the error

```
Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols
```

## Possible solution

One way I can solve this is to pass in type erased views into `CustomTabView` like so:

```swift
CustomTabView {
    AnyView(Text("A"))
    AnyView(Text("B"))
    AnyView(Rectangle())
}
```

## Ideally

but I'd like to be able to do the following just like the native `TabView`

```swift
CustomTabView {
    Text("A")
    Text("B")
    Rectangle()
}
```

So how would I go about converting the `TupleView` into an array of `AnyView`?

Comment: What is the reason for using [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror) here?

Comment: The reflection on `content` is to get the `value` property of `content` (See [here](https://medium.com/@prenezisbell_13570/a-short-note-on-viewbuilder-content-and-a-custom-vstack-in-swiftui-3f4f78629572) for more information about the `value` property). The reflection on `value` (a `TupleView`) is for iterating over the tuple.

Comment: @youjin I am trying to do the exact same thing, did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @Brett no, I did not find a solution to this, so I went about another way to create a custom tab view. I'm not sure if it's the right way, but if you'd like to see it, let me know and I can post it!

Comment: @youjin Would love to see it, please post :-)

Comment: @Brett pay me :-) Jk, I've posted it! Let me know what you think

Comment: You might find George Elsham’s ViewExtractor library helpful: https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I went about creating a custom tab view with SwiftUI:

```swift
struct CustomTabView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: Model

    let content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            return ZStack {
                // pages
                // onAppear on all pages are called only on initial load
                self.pagesInHStack(screenGeometry: geometry)
            }
            .overlayPreferenceValue(CustomTabItemPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
                // tab bar
                return self.createTabBar(screenGeometry: geometry, tabItems: preferences.map {TabItem(tag: $0.tag, tab: $0.item)})
            }
        }
    }

    func getTabBarHeight(screenGeometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        // https://medium.com/@hacknicity/ipad-navigation-bar-and-toolbar-height-changes-in-ios-12-91c5766809f4
        // ipad 50
        // iphone && portrait 49
        // iphone && portrait && bottom safety 83
        // iphone && landscape 32
        // iphone && landscape && bottom safety 53
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            return 50 + screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            if !model.landscape {
                return 49 + screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            } else {
                return 32 + screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            }
        }
        return 50
    }

    func pagesInHStack(screenGeometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {

        let tabBarHeight = getTabBarHeight(screenGeometry: screenGeometry)
        let heightCut = tabBarHeight - screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        let spacing: CGFloat = 100 // so pages don't overlap (in case of leading and trailing safetyInset), arbitrary

        return HStack(spacing: spacing) {
            self.content()
                // reduced height, so items don't appear under tha tab bar
                .frame(width: screenGeometry.size.width, height: screenGeometry.size.height - heightCut)
                // move up to cover the reduced height
                // 0.1 for iPhone X's nav bar color to extend to status bar
                .offset(y: -heightCut/2 - 0.1)
        }
        .frame(width: screenGeometry.size.width, height: screenGeometry.size.height, alignment: .leading)
        .offset(x: -CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * screenGeometry.size.width + -CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * spacing)
    }

    func createTabBar(screenGeometry: GeometryProxy, tabItems: [TabItem]) -> some View {

        let height = getTabBarHeight(screenGeometry: screenGeometry)

        return VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack(spacing: screenGeometry.size.width / (CGFloat(tabItems.count + 1) + 0.5)) {
                Spacer()
                ForEach(0..<tabItems.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    Group {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.currentIndex = i
                        }) {
                            tabItems[i].tab
                        }.foregroundColor(self.currentIndex == i ? .blue : .gray)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            // move up from bottom safety inset
            .padding(.bottom, screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 ? screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom - 5 : 0 )
            .frame(width: screenGeometry.size.width, height: height)
            .background(
                self.getTabBarBackground(screenGeometry: screenGeometry)
            )
        }
        // move down to cover bottom of new iphones and ipads
        .offset(y: screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
    }

    func getTabBarBackground(screenGeometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {

        return GeometryReader { tabBarGeometry in
            self.getBackgrounRectangle(tabBarGeometry: tabBarGeometry)
        }
    }

    func getBackgrounRectangle(tabBarGeometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {

        return VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .opacity(0.8)
                // border top
                // https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/dehx9t/how_to_add_border_only_to_bottom/
                .padding(.top, 0.2)
                .background(Color.gray)

                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing])
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the preference and view extensions:

```swift
// MARK: - Tab Item Preference
struct CustomTabItemPreferenceData: Equatable {
    var tag: Int
    let item: AnyView
    let stringDescribing: String // to let preference know when the tab item is changed
    var badgeNumber: Int // to let preference know when the badgeNumber is changed


    static func == (lhs: CustomTabItemPreferenceData, rhs: CustomTabItemPreferenceData) -> Bool {
        lhs.tag == rhs.tag && lhs.stringDescribing == rhs.stringDescribing && lhs.badgeNumber == rhs.badgeNumber
    }
}

struct CustomTabItemPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {

    typealias Value = [CustomTabItemPreferenceData]

    static var defaultValue: [CustomTabItemPreferenceData] = []

    static func reduce(value: inout [CustomTabItemPreferenceData], nextValue: () -> [CustomTabItemPreferenceData]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

// TabItem
extension View {
    func customTabItem<Content>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View where Content: View {
        self.preference(key: CustomTabItemPreferenceKey.self, value: [
            CustomTabItemPreferenceData(tag: 0, item: AnyView(content()), stringDescribing: String(describing: content()), badgeNumber: 0)
        ])
    }
}

// Tag
extension View {
    func customTag(_ tag: Int, badgeNumber: Int = 0) -> some View {

        self.transformPreference(CustomTabItemPreferenceKey.self) { (value: inout [CustomTabItemPreferenceData]) in

            guard value.count > 0 else { return }
            value[0].tag = tag
            value[0].badgeNumber = badgeNumber

        }
        .transformPreference(CustomTabItemPreferenceKey.self) { (value: inout [CustomTabItemPreferenceData]) -> Void in

            guard value.count > 0 else { return }
            value[0].tag = tag
            value[0].badgeNumber = badgeNumber
        }
        .tag(tag)
    }
}
```

and here's the usage:

```swift
struct MainTabsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // TabView
        CustomTabView {
            A()
                .customTabItem { ... }
                .customTag(0, badgeNumber: 1)
            B()
                .customTabItem { ... }
                .customTag(2)
            C()
                .customTabItem { ... }
                .customTag(3)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that's useful to y'all out there, let me know if you know a better way!

Comment: The use of the Preferences to pass info back to the container is brilliant. It looks like a lot of work went into this. Thanks a lot for posting the complete solution, I am sure this is going to be useful to many people. The cheque is in the mail @youjin ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I created [`IterableViewBuilder`](https://github.com/dankinsoid/IterableView/blob/main/Sources/IterableView/IterableViewBuilder.swift) for this purpose

```
struct ContentView: View {
...

  init<C: IterableView>(@IterableViewBuilder content: () -> C) {
    let count = content().count
    content().iterate(with: Visitor())
  }
}

struct Visitor: IterableViewVisitor {
  func visit<V>(_ value: V) where V : View {
    print("value")
  }
}
...

ContentView {
  Text("0")
  Text("1")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a native approach to accomplish this via the `_VariadicView.MultiViewRoot` or `_VariadicView.UnaryViewRoot` protocols.

*Using internal APIs is generally discouraged because they can change or be removed in future updates, but it's the only approach that works well.*

You need to implement one of these protocols. Then, in the `body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View` method, you can iterate through all subviews (`_VariadicView.Children` is a `Collection`). Your implementation and children should be wrapped with the `_VariadicView.Tree` view.

The choice between the two depends on your needs: if you want a view that behaves like an array of views and can be placed in a `VStack` or `HStack` etc, you would use `_VariadicView.MultiViewRoot`. On the other hand, if you need a single standalone view, `_VariadicView.UnaryViewRoot` would be the way to go.

Here's an example:

```swift
public struct WithSeparator<Separator: View>: ViewModifier {

    public var separator: Separator

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        _VariadicView.Tree(Root(base: self)) {
            content
        }
    }

    private struct Root: _VariadicView.MultiViewRoot {

        let base: WithSeparator
        @Environment(\.separatorLocation)
        private var separatorLocation

        func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View {
            if !children.isEmpty {
                if separatorLocation.contains(.start) {
                    base.separator
                }
                ForEach(Array(children.dropLast())) { child in
                    child
                    if separatorLocation.contains(.between) {
                        base.separator
                    }
                }
                children[children.count - 1]
                if separatorLocation.contains(.end) {
                    base.separator
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public extension View {

    func separator(@ViewBuilder _ separator: () -> some View) -> some View {
        modifier(WithSeparator(separator: separator()))
    }
}
```

This code creates a `WithSeparator` struct that uses the `_VariadicView.MultiViewRoot` protocol. This allows you to add a separator between your views.

```swift
VStack {
   ForEach(...) { 
      ...
   }.separator {
      Color.black.frame(height: 1)
   }
}
```