# SwiftUI is there any way to create a TabView that displays the View below Tab Item

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there any way to create a TabView that displays the View below Tab Item so its the opposite of the default TabView where it Displays the view above the tab item.

Not asking for code but just wondering if theres any SwiftUI component to achieve that or if anyone knows any external libraries that would be helpful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to create your own custom `TabView`. Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608417/swiftui-casting-tupleview-to-an-array-of-anyview) to see how I did it.